# How do you show goals in Crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a Crystal Report that groups proposal amounts by specified amounts. The development officers have campaign goals for each specified amount. How can I incorporate these goals into the report?

Comment: incomplete information.... if you expect answers then to the minimum show efforts and at least show the design of the report on how you would like to view the report.

Comment: @Siva, I was initially stumped, and didn't know what to try at first, but I came up with something on my own that worked does the trick for now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I wanted by putting the goal data in a formula in crystal reports. Ideally though the goals should be in the database, and you just import them in a field, but this was the work around I made:

In this example, the fundraisers had goals for number of donations within a certain dollar range, so based on that range I put the goal number in it's own formula field in the group header.

```
if {Amount_Expected} >= 500 then 4
else
if {Amount_Expected} >= 250 then 6
else
if {Amount_Expected} >= 100 then 10
```

Etc, etc...